# Simulation veins-run has encountered a problem. Simulation terminated with exit code: -1073740940

Tags: omnet++, veins

I use Omnet++ 5.4.1 Veins 4.7.1 and Sumo 30.
My simulation works well and generates the right output
But when the simulation time runs end or I stop the simulation, it shows the following error:

> simulation veins-run' has encountered a problem. finish with error
>     Simulation terminated with exit code: -1073740940
>   Working directory: C:/Users/AB/src/omnetpp-5.4.1/samples/veins/examples/veins
>   Command line: ../../../../bin/opp_run.exe -m -u Qtenv -n .;../../src/veins --image-path=../../images -l ../../src/veins omnetpp.ini
>   Environment variables:
>   PATH=;C:/Users/AB/src/omnetpp-5.4.1/samples/veins/src;C:\Users\AB\src\omnetpp-5.4.1\bin;C:\Users\AB\src\omnetpp-5.4.1\tools\win64\mingw64\bin;C:\Users\AB\src\omnetpp-5.4.1\tools\win64\usr\bin;;C:/Users/AB/src/omnetpp-5.4.1/ide/jre/bin/server;C:/Users/AB/src/omnetpp-5.4.1/ide/jre/bin;C:/Users/AB/src/omnetpp-5.4.1/ide/jre/lib/amd64;.;C:\Users\AB\src\omnetpp-5.4.1\bin;C:\Users\AB\src\omnetpp-5.4.1\tools\win64\mingw64\bin;C:\Users\AB\src\omnetpp-5.4.1\tools\win64\usr\local\bin;C:\Users\AB\src\omnetpp-5.4.1\tools\win64\usr\bin;C:\Users\AB\src\omnetpp-5.4.1\tools\win64\usr\bin;C:\Windows\System32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Users\AB\src\omnetpp-5.4.1\tools\win64\usr\bin\site_perl;C:\Users\AB\src\omnetpp-5.4.1\tools\win64\usr\bin\vendor_perl;C:\Users\AB\src\omnetpp-5.4.1\tools\win64\usr\bin\core_perl;C:\Users\AB\src\omnetpp-5.4.1;
>   OMNETPP_ROOT=C:/Users/AB/src/omnetpp-5.4.1/
>   OMNETPP_IMAGE_PATH=C:\Users\AB\src\omnetpp-5.4.1\images

And the `finish()` method doesn't work, and I can't record the information and use it to draw chart.
Please help me to solve my problem.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In your `omnetpp.ini` set:

```
debug-on-errors = true
```

and start the simulation in debug mode. The debugger should show the command that causes an error. Reference: [OMNeT++ Tutorial - 2.3 Debugging](https://docs.omnetpp.org/tutorials/tictoc/part2/#23-debugging)

Another clue: unfortunately OMNeT++ uses decimal numbers for exit code, while hex values are more valuable. The exit code `-1073740940` has the hex representation: `0xc0000374`. One may use the last number for looking among Microsoft Windows exception codes.

Comment: Thank you for your answer
I think I realized the problem.

Comment: Mr  @Jerzy D. befor  simulation debugging ,it worked well and   I was getting the right outputs and just when the simulation  finished It showed me the above error

Comment: The things I did to debug it : I right-clicked on the .ini file  Then I selected Debua AS omnet++ simulation  and it started debugging. Then I run the simulation, but after that, it showed me an error.that is in Mac1909_4.cc file

Comment: Assertion failed!
Program: C:\Users\AB\src\omnetpp-5.4.1\bin\opp_run_dbg.exe
File: veins/modules/mac/ieee80211p/Mac1609_4.cc, Line 442  .Expression: state == type_CCH || (useSCH && state == type_SCH)
Simulation terminated with exit code: 3